# Buffer only if clicked on play button in a youtube video in Chrome HTML5

Tags: google-chrome, video, flash, youtube, html5

To save bandwidth, is it possible to buffer a video only if play button or some other button is clicked?

I basically want to open youtube pages or other embedded videos, only for seeing the comments or notes. I don't want to view the videos.

If I click on pause button, then the video still buffers to the end.

Currently, my mode is set to HTML5. 
Flash Player is quite slow, but if there is no solution for HTML5, I'll shift to Flash Player.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the HTML and you are using the `<video>` tag, you can provide the [attribute `preload="none"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload) which according to MDN means:

> none: indicates that the video should not be preloaded

And, make sure that `autoplay` is not specified.

You could also not even build and insert the `<video>` tag until an appropriate click happens.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the OP controls the HTML for youtube pages ...

Comment: I was actually doing this for videos on the page like: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud775/l-2980038599/m-2960778931

Comment: I actually wanted this for videos on the page: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud775/l-2980038599/m-2960778931 . I posted there: https://discussions.udacity.com/t/dont-buffer-video-automatically/38195/2 and the solution is working. I thought to make a chrome extension but it doesn't work: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bxg0L-sj9zVtQ0dUaGhLYXVRZU0&usp=sharing Anyone can edit the above extension by editing there.